# Найти разницу полей в двух объектах, полученных при помощи методов min/max в Stream API

Tags: java, объекты, java-stream, max, min

Есть список каких-то людей. Нужно этот список передать в метод, найти в нем самого молодого и самого старого, затем найти разницу между их зарплатами.

Собственно в "передать в другой метод" никаких проблем нет. Через стрим найти самого молодого и самого старого тоже могу.

Есть класс `Employees` с приватными полями и соответствующими геттерами и список `List<Employees>`:

```java
public class Employees { 
    private String name; 
    private String secondName; 
    private int salary; 
    private int age;
    // геттеры, сеттеры, конструктор 
}
```

Самого молодого и самого старого нахожу так:

```java
Object oldestEmployee = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Employees::getAge)); 
Object youngestEmployee = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Employees::getAge));
```

Как найти разницу в зарплате, если новые объекты не принимают поля старых объектов?
Возможно ли это сделать через стрим, чтобы не прописывать огромный кусок кода?

Comment: при чем тут "новые объекты не принимают поля старых объектов"? зачем тут вообще новые объекты?

Comment: Что мешает просто вычесть из зарплаты старого зарплату молодого после того, как они были найдены?

Comment: У меня есть ещё большая проблема с объяснением проблемы. Проблема моя состоит в том, что я не знаю как это прописать. При нахождении двух работников-я не могу вызвать поля, в которых прописана ЗП.

Comment: @PavelPavlik Проблема с объяснением не является проблемой на этом сайте. В вопросе надо задавать только одну проблему и конкретизировать ее максимально, чтобы можно было дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: "я не могу вызвать поля, в которых прописана ЗП". Но почему? Они приватные?

Comment: Есть класс Employees с приватными полями: public class Employees {

    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private int salary;
    private int age;
      есть список. самого молодого и самого старого нахожу так: Object oldestEmployee = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Employees::getAge));
        Object youngestEmployee = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Employees::getAge)); но как найти разницу в их ЗП?

Comment: `Object oldestEmployee = ...` -> `Employees oldestEmployee = ...`.

Comment: @Nofate, для `Stream::min/Stream::max` возвращается класс-обёртка `Optional<Employees>`, а не непосредственно экземпляр класса, поэтому у него и нет геттеров основного класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Терминальные операции [`Stream::min`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) и [`Stream::max`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) возвращают тип `Optional<T>`.

Этот тип представляет собой обёртку для обработки возможных `null` значений (у пустого потока минимальное и максимальное значения будут отсутствовать, и тогда будет возвращаться "пустой" объект [`Optional.empty`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/Optional.html#empty--)).  Разумеется, у типа `Optional` нет геттеров соответствующего класса.

Поэтому для поиска зарплаты самого старого и самого молодого сотрудника можно использовать методы [`Optional::map`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) (для вызова геттера зарплаты) и [`Optional::orElse`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) для обработки пустого значения.

```java
public static int calcSalaryDifference(List<Employees> employees) {
    int oldestSalary = employees.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Employees::getAge)) // Optional<Employees>
        .map(Employees::getSalary) // Optional<Integer>
        .orElse(0);

    int youngestSalary = employees.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Employees::getAge)) // Optional<Employees>
        .map(Employees::getSalary) // Optional<Integer>
        .orElse(0);

    return youngestSalary - oldestSalary;
}
```

---

Найти зарплаты самого старшего и самого младшего сотрудника можно и за один проход при помощи метода [`Stream::reduce`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), также возвращающего `Optional<T>` значения, и класса/кортежа (record) для хранения пары "младший - старший".

```java
record YoungOld(Employees youngest, Employees oldest) {
    YoungOld(Employees e) {
        this(e, e);
    }
}

public static int calcSalaryDifferenceOneRun(List<Employees> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
        .map(YoungOld::new) // Stream<YoungOld>
        .reduce((a, b) -> new YoungOld(
            a.getAge() < b.getAge() ? a : b, // младший из двух
            a.getAge() > b.getAge() ? a : b  // старший из двух
        )) // Optional<YoungOld>
        .map(yo -> yo.youngest().getSalary() - yo.oldest().getSalary())
        .orElse(0);
}
```